# Ruby Enumerables -- what are they exactly?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Can someone explain in the most basic, laymans terms what a Ruby `Enumerable` is? I'm very new to coding and just starting to work with arrays and hashes. I read the word "Enumerables" everywhere but I don't understand what they are.

Comment: Basically, it's an object that knows how to `.each`.  See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html for details about the Enumerable mixin.

Comment: Awesome: "it's an object that knows how to .each." That is exactly what I needed to read. Thank you so much for the simple clarification!

Comment: One day, long ago, a very wise Rubyest from the land of the Rising Sun noticed that many methods he used for arrays were very similar to those he used for hashes, ranges and other collections.  He saw that he could write them so that the only difference was how the method `each` was implemented, so he put them all in a module he called "可算の" ("Enumerable"), and then in all the classes for different types of collections (`Array`, `Hash`, `Range`, `Set`, etc.) he added `include Enumerable` and a method `each`. After doing this, he thought, "生活は快適です" ("life is good").

Comment: Thank you for this! Laymans terms and a tale to boot -- I'm gaining so much clarity here. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain in the most basic, laymans terms what a Ruby
>   Enumerable is?

It's a module that defines a bunch of methods, and when another class includes that module, those methods are available in that class. So if someone uses a method like `each_with_index` on an Array, and you say to yourself, "I wonder how that method works.  I'll check the Array docs.", you won't find that method in the Array docs.  When you are searching for a method definition, and you can't find it in the Array docs, you need to examine the Array docs to see what modules are included by the Array class; then you will see that Array includes Enumerable.  So you can click the Enumerable link, and there you will find the definition for each_with_index.   Try it.

I think what you really mean is: What is an Enumerator?

And an Enumerator is a thing that can step through(i.e. *iterate*) the elements of a collection(Array, Hash, etc.).  However, if you just started coding, the only thing you need to worry about is how to find the definitions of methods in the docs, and hopefully the above will sort that out.  Enumerators are out on the horizon of your future.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html):

> The Enumerable mixin provides collection classes with several
>   traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. The
>   class must provide a method each, which yields successive members of
>   the collection.