# What is the relationship between Array and Enumerable?

Tags: ruby, arrays

`Array` doesn't have `sort_by`; `Enumerable` has it. How does this work?

```
%w[aa aaaa aaa].sort_by{|item| item.length} #=> ['aa','aaa','aaaa']
```

Doesn't this have to throw an error like `undefined method sort_by`? What is the relationship between `Array` and `Enumerable`?

Comment: Array includes Enumerable

Comment: It feels like this _should_ be a duplicate of something, but if it is I can't find it. So, +1.

Comment: I left a comment to an [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227668/ruby-enumerables-what-are-they-exactly) that provides a plausible explanation of how the `Enumerable` module came into existence.

Comment: @apneadiving, a quibble: Most readers will understand what you said is shorthand for "The class Array contains the statement 'include Enumerable'", but I think "The class Array mixes-in the Enumerable module" is clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Array` class includes the `Enumerable` module. You can see that in the documentation on the left under "Included Modules".

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable` is mixed into the `Array` class: all methods defined by Enumerable are available to Ruby arrays.

`Array.ancestors # => [Array, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Answer (score 0):

This is called *inheritance*. If a method isn't found in an object's class, Ruby walks up the ancestors chain until it finds it.

`Array` inherits from `Enumerable` (more precisely, it *mixes in* `Enumerable`, which is a form of inheritance).

Comment: No inheritance is involved in this case, though. It is just plain method delegation to the mixed in module (Enumerable in this case)

Comment: @HectorCorrea: there is no delegation here. `Array` doesn't delegate to (an instance of) `Enumerable`, it inherits from it (more precisely: it mixes it in, which is a form of inheritance where the mixed in "class" doesn't know its superclass until it is mixed in).

Comment: @Hector, if that were the case there would be no point in the class `Array` having methods like `take_while`, which are also provided by `Enumerable`. Since `Enumerable` methods serve multiple classes of collections, they are in some cases not as efficient as the same method tailored for a specific class.  It is for that reason that you will see many methods for collection classes that have the same names as `Enumerable` methods.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I never questioned the value of mixins. My point was to warn that inheritance and mixins are two different things.

Comment: Hector, it occurred to me that there are reasons other than improved efficiency for providing methods in collection classes that have counterparts in the mixed-in `Enumerable` module. Here's an example of a method that gives a different result: `(0.0..1.0).include?(0.5) #=> true; Range.send(:remove_method, :include?); (0.0..1.0).include?(0.5) #=> TypeError: can't iterate from Float`. Here [Range#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) is equivalent to `Range#cover` when the end-points are numeric, whereas `Enumerable#include?` does not.

Comment: @Hector, in that case I misunderstood what you meant by "plain method delegation".

Comment: @HectorCorrea: Mixins originated in Flavors, where they were not an explicit language construct, but just a specific idiom for how to use **inheritance**. The seminal paper which defines and clarifies the semantics of mixins is called [Mixin-based **inheritance**](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/papers/MixinBasedInheritance/MixinBasedInheritance.pdf). In it, it is shown how mixin inheritance subsumes all other known forms of linear **inheritance**, namely traditional class **inheritance** as in Smalltalk (which also applies to Java, C#, Ruby etc.), *prefixing* as in Beta and linearized …

Comment: … multiple class **inheritance** as in CLOS (which also applies to Dylan, Python, C++ etc.). In C++ and Python, mixins are a specific way of using **inheritance**. In all currently existing Ruby implementations (with the possible exception of Cardinal, about which I don't know enough to definitely comment on it), mixing a mixin `M` into a class `C` is implemented by copying the module's method table, constant table, and class variable table into a class `M'` and making `M'` the superclass of `C`, IOW mixin inheritance is implemented using class **inheritance**. …

Comment: … To me, that makes them very closely related indeed, and definitely *not* "two different things".

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for the link to the paper, it looks interesting. I'll take a look at it. My problem with your answer is that saying that "Array inherits from Enumerable" is incorrect. But I agree with the later part "more precisely, it mixes in Enumerable". Fundamentally, I don't think mixins are "a form of inheritance". If anything it's the other way around inheritance is a form of mixin (the conclusion of the paper alludes to this: "inheritance is interpreted as mixin composition".) So inheritance is a form of mixin (which I didn't know until now) but the reverse is not necessarily true.

Comment: @JörgWMittag by the way, I learned quite a bit in this discussion. Thanks!